# What can pointers do that are otherwise impossible to implement?

Tags: pointers

So I'm having a hard time grasping the idea behind pointers and all that memory allocation.

I'm thinking nowadays with computer as powerful as they are right now why do we have to use pointers at all?

Isn't there always a workaround to do things without the help of pointers?

Comment: It kind of depends on the language. With C++, basically no. Pointers are really important in that language. Also the same for Java (sort of). Also, some C libraries make heavy use of them (like Glib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are an indirection: instead of working with the data itself, you are working with (something) that points to the data.  Depending on the semantics of the language, this allows many things: cheaply switch to another instance of data (by setting the pointer to point to another instance), passing pointers allows access to the original data without having to make (a possibly expensive) copy, etc.

Memory allocation is related to pointers, but separate: you can have pointers without allocating memory.  The reason you need pointers for memory allocation is that the actual address the allocated block of memory resides is not known at compile time, so you can only access it via a level of indirection (i.e. pointers) -- the compiler statically allocates space for the pointer that will point to the dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Pointers (or the equivalent at the VM/machine) are *required* to have [Call By Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) which, if you believe in mutability, is a *must* in most "OO" languages. That is, it's not just that passing data can be expensive: a copy is a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are incredibly powerful. Just because computers have a faster processing time nowdays, doesn't mean that's any reason to abandon something as essential as pointers. Passing around giant chunks of memory on the stack is inefficient at best, catastrophic at worst. With pointers, you only need to maintain a reference to where the data resides, rather than duplicating huge chunks of memory each time you call a function.

Also, if you're copying all the data every time, how do you modify the original data? Aside from returning the copy of the structure in every call that touches it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere that Dijkstra was assessing a student for a programming course; this student was quite intelligent but s/he wasn't able to solve the problem because there was sort of a mental block.

All the code was sort of ok, but what was needed was simply to use the expression

```
a[a[i+1]] = j;
```

and even if being so close to the solution still the goal seemed to be miles away.

Languages "without pointers" already exist... e.g. BASIC. Without **explicit** pointers, that is. But the indirection idea... the idea that you can have data to mean just where to find other data is central to programming.

The very idea of array is about being able to use computed values to find other values.

Trying to hide this idea is an horrible plan. According to Dijkstra anyone that has been exposed to the BASIC language has already received such a mental mutilation that is impossible to recover as a good programmer (and probably the absence of explicit indirection was one of the problems).

I think he was exaggerating.

Just a bit.

Comment: i think i suffer from that "mental block" that you mentioned. there are some concepts in programming that i cant just "get it". pointers, arrays, boolean values to mention a few

Comment: The array concept is probably the most important to metabolize first so I'd suggest to play a lot with them. I was lucky because my first programming language was assembler and more or less all I had available to have fun was an array of 65536 elements. Pointers and array indexes are not that different on a philosophical plane. About the boolean value there's really not much to understand, it's just one of the possible interpretations of a single bit of information. Either do or do not. Yes or no. White or black. True or false. Zero or one.